# c# get value from registry without parameters

Tags: c#, static, registry

I am trying to get the path to AcroRd32.exe by invoking the following code:

```
 public static string acrobatPath = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\AcroRD32.exe\shell\Read\command", "", 0).ToString();
```

What I receive is the right value:

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "%1"
```

but I want only the path to AcroRd32.exe without "%1".
I could now use the split command:

```
public static string acrobatPath = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\AcroRD32.exe\shell\Read\command", "", 0).ToString();
string[] split = new string[2];
split = acrobatPath.Split('"');
// mask path with ""
acrobatPath = "\"" + split[1] + "\""; //get only path
```

but the value acrobatPath cannot be changed because of static attribute.

I also cannot use substr() because path can differ e.g. if there is no parameter at the end ("%1").

How can I extract the path and set the static variable in one go?

Comment: Could you not put acrobatPath into another static variable after you have split it?

Comment: The point is that I need a method that formats the key. I could make a method keyFormat() that uses the above split command but then I have the problem that the other static variable has to exist before I call the keyFormat() method. If I try to write the split in the class there is an error: otherAcrobatPath is an attribute variable but is used as a type variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use static constructor for your class, and do all the work for string manipulation there.

```
class YourClass
{
    public static string acrobatPath;
    // This static constructor will be called before first access to your type.
    static YourClass()
    {
        acrobatPath = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\AcroRD32.exe\shell\Read\command", "", 0).ToString();
        string[] split = new string[2];
        split = acrobatPath.Split('"');
        // mask path with ""
        acrobatPath = "\"" + split[1] + "\""; //get only path
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that a constructor is only called if I make an instance. Is it also called if I just call a method without making an instance?

Comment: Look closer, this is a STATIC constructor. The constructor for Type, not the instance. It is called only once per AppDomain, right before the type is accessed. So when you have YourType.acrobatPath accessed for the first time anywhere outside YourType, static constructor will be called before that.

Comment: Just tried it and realized the static. Thx, for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
but the value acrobatPath cannot be changed because of static attribute.
```

This statement makes no sense.  You can change a static variable.  The way your using the static string to be set the to the value of the register key ( which isn't going to change if it does exist ) is the reason you cannot change it.

The solution would be to change how the code works to be a method.

As you have already accepted Vladimir Perevalov's answer I won't go into a great amount of detail.  What I would do is the following:

1) Get the installation directory of Adobe Reader by reading the installation directory.  I would set this to a variable which I was able to modify at will.

2) I would modify the string only to get the path

3) I would set the current value of this string I just create to the static variable.

This does exactly what Vladimir Perevalov's code does, it simply uses a function, instead of a class.  Of course the method would be static and in the same class as the static variable.  Of course there is nothing wrong with using a STATIC constructor, I always have considered a constructor to be a specialized method, I just wanted to point out you CAN modify a static variable.